# Making custom performance counters (separate instance for each controller-action) with Application Insights in an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I have read the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-performance-counters/) (see heading "Collecting performance counters in code"), relevant code snippet is below.
(To collect performance counters and send them to Application Insights with custom metrics)

```
var perfCollectorModule = new PerformanceCollectorModule();
perfCollectorModule.Counters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(
  @"\Sales(photo)\# Items Sold", "Photo sales"));
perfCollectorModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
```

Let's say I want to have a counter for average latency for each controller-action. So now the counter *category* would be "ActionSpecificCounters" and the *instance* would be a string with the controller-action combination in it and  the counter *name* can be "ActionLatency".
Now, my questions:

**Question 1:**
How do I add a new counter like in the documentation snippet when I don't know all the possible counter instances (controller-action combinations) in advance at app start time? Is there a way to add them on-the-go (I suppose I cannot call Initialize multiple times?)?
I would know controller-action combinations in OnActionExecut(ed/ing).

**Question 2:**
I am assuming I would have to make a custom metric for each controller-action combination first, before I can add a counter on top of it? How do I link a custom counter to the underlying custom metric?
For custom metric I can do something like:

```
var controllerActionLatencyMetricName = controllerName + "-" actionName + "-Latency";
telemetry.TrackMetric(controllerActionLatencyMetricName, latency);
```

but then how do I add a custom counter on top of this metric?

```
perfCollectorModule.Counters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(
  @"what-do-I-put-here?",controllerActionLatencyMetricName));
```

Am I just supposed to use the metric name (controllerActionLatencyMetricName) as the instance name, making a string like the following?

```
@"\ActionSpecificCounters("+controllerActionLatencyMetricName+")\ActionLatency"
```